# Change UIDatePicker hour and minute fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidatepicker

Is it possible to disable a `UIDatePicker` hour and minuet fields with a switch? So lets say..

```
if(hourSwitch.on){
    // turn hh mm on
}else{
    // turn hh and mm off
}
```

Comment: Check the UIDatePicker class reference property `datePickerMode`.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't simply consult the spec?

Comment: @HotLicks where is the spec?

Comment: The place they all are: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action (Use the search window in the upper right)  Also, Xcode=>Window=>Organizer=>Documentation.  Hard to believe that you can begin to develop iOS apps without knowing how to find the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can change datepicker mode:

```
if(hourSwitch.on){
    // turn hh mm on
        yourdatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

}else{
    // turn hh and mm off
        yourdatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

}
```

Hope it helps you.